# MEMORY MAP for 2d / multidimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management, 2d

Can anyone please explain **visually** as to how the 2D array is stored in memory as:
a , &a, &a[0] , a[0] all have the same address...
It seems like a pointer pointing to itself in a way...and that cant be right...
This has been bugging me for nearly a year and searching on the web has lead me to no apt answer as well..... help is really appreciated....thanx

```
enter code here

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2][3]={10,20,30,40,50,60};

    int row =0,col=0;

    printf("&a = %d ",&a);    
    printf("\na = %d ",a);
    printf("\n&a[0] = %d ",&a[0]);
    printf("\na[0] = %d ",a[0]);
    printf("\n&a[1] = %d ",&a[1]);
    printf("\na[1] = %d ",a[1]);
    printf("\n&a[0][0] = %d ",&a[0][0]);

    int *p;
    printf("\n\n sizeof(p) = %d ",sizeof(p) );

    printf("\n\n sizeof(a) = %d ",sizeof(a) );
    printf("\n\n sizeof(&a) = %d ",sizeof(&a) );
    printf("\n\n sizeof(&a[0]) = %d ",sizeof(&a[0]) );
    printf("\n\n sizeof(a[0]) = %d ",sizeof(a[0]) );
    printf("\n\n sizeof(&a[1]) = %d ",sizeof(&a[1]) );
    printf("\n\n sizeof(a[1]) = %d ",sizeof(a[1]) );
    printf("\n\n sizeof(&a[0][0]) = %d ",sizeof(&a[0][0]) );
}
```

---

### OUTPUT

```
&a = 2293536
a = 2293536
&a[0] = 2293536
a[0] = 2293536
&a[1] = 2293548
a[1] = 2293548
&a[0][0] = 2293536

sizeof(p) = 4

sizeof(a) = 24

sizeof(&a) = 4

sizeof(&a[0]) = 4

sizeof(a[0]) = 12

sizeof(&a[1]) = 4

sizeof(a[1]) = 12

sizeof(&a[0][0]) = 4
```

Don't refer me to [Memory map for a 2D array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673719/memory-map-for-a-2d-array-in-c)  ... that didnt help ...

Comment: Refer "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868003/pointers-with-two-dimensional-array/12869239#12869239" which describes similiar context

Answer (score 5):

So the array `a` is one object taking up a block of memory:

```
| a                                                         |
```

It's an array of length 2, so if we draw in the elements that make it up it looks like this:

```
| a[0]                        | a[1]                        |
```

`a[0]` in turn is an array of length 3, and looks like this:

```
| a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[0][2] |
```

`a[1]` looks the same, so we can redraw the array `a` to look like this:

```
| a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[0][2] | a[1][0] | a[1][1] | a[1][2] |
```

Notice that `a`, `a[0]` and `a[0][0]` are all located at the same point in memory: the start of the object `a`.  However, they do have different sizes: `a` is the entire "2D array", `a[0]` is a regular array, and `a[0][0]` is a single `int.

This explains why `&a`, `&a[0]` and `&a[0][0]` are the same addresses (though they have different types) - they're the addresses of things located at the same point in memory.

Additionally, there's a rule that if an array is evaluated in an expression where it's not the subject of the unary `&` or `sizeof` operators, it evaluates to a pointer to its first element: that is, using a plain `a` is equivalent to `&a[0]`.  Since `a[0]` is also an array, using a plain `a[0]` is equivalent to `&a[0][0]`.  This explains why `a` and `a[0]` 
also evaluate to the same addresses as `&a`, `&a[0]` and `&a[0][0]`.

The fact that the address of an array and the adddress of the first element in that array are the same isn't really surprising: the same thing happens with `struct`, too.  Given:

```
struct { int a; int b; } x;
```

You'll find that `&x` and `&x.a` are the same address (albeit with different types).

Comment: may i know the source of the rule?

and when i use 'a' it means im using address of 'a' 
and when using '&a' it means im pointing to 'a' ....therego doesnt it mean a points to itself ????

Comment: @VishnuKumaar: The source of the rule is the C standard - it is defined in §6.3.2.1 in C99.  The array doesn't point anywhere because it's not a pointer, it's an array.  In most expressions `a` *evaluates to* a pointer to its first element, but that's not what it *is*.

Answer (score 1):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` `_Alignof`, or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

Assume the following memory map (assumes little-endian, 4-byte `int`s; addresses pulled out of thin air):

```
Item         Address          00   01   02   03    Sub array    Sub array element
----         -------          --   --   --   --    ---------    -----------------
   a         0xfffebc00       00   00   00   0a    a[0]         a[0][0]
             0xfffebc04       00   00   00   14                 a[0][1]
             0xfffebc08       00   00   00   1e                 a[0][2]
             0xfffebc0c       00   00   00   28    a[1]         a[1][0]
             0xfffebc10       00   00   00   32                 a[1][1]
             0xfffebc14       00   00   00   3c                 a[1][2]
```

Going by the rule mentioned above, the *expression* `a` will be converted from type "2-element array of 3-element array of `int`" to "pointer to 3-element array of `int`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  The first element of `a` is `a[0]`, and the address of `a[0]` is `0xfffebc00`.

Similarly, the expression `a[0]` will be converted from type "3-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`", and its value will be the address of the first element of the array.  The first element of `a[0]` is `a[0][0]`, and its address is ... `0xfffebc00`.

The expression `&a` is one of the exceptions to the rule above.  In this case, `a` is not converted to a pointer type before applying the `&` operator; the type of the expression is "pointer to 2-element array of 3-element array of `int`" (`int (*)[2][3]`), and its value is the address of `a`, which is ... `0xfffebc00`.

Similarly, the expression `&a[0]` has type "pointer to 3-element array of `int`" and its value is the address of `a[0]`, which is ... `0xfffebc00`.

Hopefully the type and value of `&a[0][0]` should be obvious.

So yes, the expressions `a`, `&a`, `*a`, `a[0]`, `&a[0]`, and `&a[0][0]` all yield the same *value*, but their types are different: `int (*)[3]`, `int (*)[2][3]`, `` `int * ``, `int *`, `int (*)[3]`, and `int *`, respectively.