# Memory map of 2d array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have confusion about 2d arrays in C. My code is:

```
main()
{
    int i, j;
    int arr[3][4] = {
                     { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                     { 5, 6, 7, 8 },
                     { 9, 0, 1, 6 }
                    };    

    printf("\narr: %u", arr);
    printf("\n&arr: %u", &arr);
    printf("\n*arr: %u", *arr);
}
```

And the Output of the above program is:

```
arr u: 3215469448
&arr: 3215469448
*arr: 3215469448
```

Now tell me how all 3 printf statements displaying address of a single location.
Just explain broadly how these addresses are same.

I know, similar question is asked earlier also, but they didn't help me. Don't refer me to [Memory map for a 2D array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673719/memory-map-for-a-2d-array-in-c) and [MEMORY MAP for 2d / multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952708/memory-map-for-2d-multidimensional-arrays) ...

Comment: *"Don't refer me to Memory map for a 2D array in C and MEMORY MAP for 2d / multidimensional arrays ..."* Why not? You have asked the same question and the answer remains the same. An array decays to a pointer and the address of the array is also that pointer and a prefix-`*` dereference on a multidimensional array returns the first lower dimensional array which decays to a pointer...

Comment: probably typo in `arr u: 3215469448`. `u` not needed. I tried to fix that, but occur error `too short fix`.

Comment: You need to do your own research across the thousands of resources on this exact same question including the two links you have provided.  Voting to close "please explain this code to me" as too localized, although yes it is also arguable this is an exact duplicate to the questions that you say did not help you.

Answer (score 1):

In memory, your array is laid out like this

```
Low address                                  High address

  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0 | 1 | 6 |
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^               ^               ^
  |               |               |
arr[0]          arr[1]          arr[2]
  ^
  |
 arr
```

As seen in the above crude ASCII-image, both `arr` and `arr[0]` points to the same memory location. And as `*arr` is the same as `arr[0]` (which is the same as `arr`) then it's easy to see why `arr` and `*arr` are the same.

The that might seem weird is that `&arr` is the same too, conventionally it should be the location of the *variable* `arr` not what it points to. The reason can be found in the C specification (§6.5.3.2/3 in the last C11 draft):

> Similarly, if the operand is the result of a [] operator, neither the & operator nor
>   the unary * that is implied by the [] is evaluated and the result is as if the & operator
>   were removed and the [] operator were changed to a + operator.

What this means is, basically, that if the address-of operator `&` is used on an array, just return the address of the array.

Answer (score 0):

At the first, `arr` point to top address of the 2d array memory block. this mean that address of variable `arr` is same as address of memory block of 2d array.

```
printf("\narr: %u", arr);
```

show the pointer value

```
printf("\n&arr: %u", &arr);
```

show an reference of variable `arr`. It's same as top address of 2d block in I said above.

```
printf("\n&arr: %u", *arr);
```

`arr` is a pointer that is pointed address of `a[0]` also, so `*arr` mean dereference of `&arr[0]`. i.e. `*&arr[0]` = `arr`.