# Arithmetic operation on multidimensional array

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am doing some arithmetic operations on multidimensional array. Also tried some code using C++. But, output of my code contradict with my theoretical understanding on relation between different pointers and multidimensional array.

My understanding on 2D and 3D array.

**2D Array**

1)[image]
Again, by using dereference operator

2)[image]

**3D Array**

3)[image]
Again, by using dereference operator

4)[image]

I am confused about what B and C pointing in figure 2 and 4 respectively.

**Code on 2D array**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){



    int B[2][2] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    cout << B << endl;
    cout << B+1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

0x7ffec3dd9f80

0x7ffec3dd9f88

Here, pointer to int B is increased by ((1*4)+(1*4)) = 8 unit that is pointer to int (B+1).
Though I got one explanation from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868003/pointers-with-two-dimensional-array) on what actually B points in 2D array. It points first element of 2D array.

Output of my code and explanation on this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868003/pointers-with-two-dimensional-array) confused me.
What actually B points in 2D array?
And, If B points the address of first element of 2D array, then why value of B is increased by 8 unit when we add 1 with it? Why not increased by (1*4) unit?

**Code on 3D array**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){



    int C[2][2][2] = {{
                    {1, 2},
                    {3, 4}
                  },
                  {
                    {1, 2},
                    {3, 4}
                  }};

    cout << C << endl;
    cout << C[0] << endl;
    cout << C[0] +1 << endl;
    cout << C[0][0] +1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

0x7ffeac58d130

0x7ffeac58d130

0x7ffeac58d138

0x7ffeac58d134

C gives starting address of whole array. But, which portion specifically it points? Is it pointing &C[0] or &C[0][0] or&C[0][0][0]?

```
cout << C[0]+1 << endl; here, C[0] is increased by 8 unit. But, if C[0] is pointing the base address of 1st 2D array inside 3D array, then it must be increased by 16 unit to get base &C[1].

cout << C[0][0] +1 << endl; here, C[0][0] is increased by 4 unit. But if it is pointing the base address of 1st 1D array of 1st 2D array inside 3D array, then it must be increased by 8 unit to get base &C[0][1].
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diagrams 1 and 3 are correct Diagrams 2 and 4 are not.  `*B` and `B[0]` are defined to mean exactly the same thing.  Similarly with `**B` and `B[0][0]`.

So to fix Diagram 2, actually copy Diagram 1 but merely change the text `B[0]` to `*B` and so on.   `B` by itself refers to the whole array.   Ditto for Diagram 4.

`B+1` is defined as meaning `&(B[1])`, it refers to a temporary pointer pointing at the object you have correctly marked as `B[1]` in Diagram 1.

In `cout << B << endl;`, treat `B` as saying `B+0` (i.e. `&(B[0])`). When you use an array in a context where a pointer is expected, that is what happens (a temporary pointer is created, it behaves the same as if you had written `&B[0]` instead of `B`).  That statement does not output B, it outputs the value of this temporary pointer.

Comment: Then, C[0] == *C, C[0][0] == **C and C[0][0][0] == ***C. Am I correct?

Comment: @zipperblock `C[0]` has exactly the same meaning as `*C` , etc.  I avoid saying `==` because that is an operator which performs conversions on its arguments.  As an expression, the last one might not even be possible if you used a struct type instead of `int` for example.

Comment: If I want output from *(B +1), it gives base address of 2nd 1D array address in 2D array. But, B is &B[0] as you said then adding one it will give &B[1] and by dereferencing that is *(&B[1]) it is giving &B[1][0]. Am i correct?

Comment: @zipperblock `*&X` means `X`. So `*&B[1]` is `B[1]`.